# vs code can not import python package but terminal can import

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-import

I installed anaconda for python3.

I clone a package from GitHub(can not install by pip3) and set the path to python in `～/.bash_profile`.
In the terminal, I can import the package successfully. when I run scripts with vs code, error info occurred: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named mypackage
I run `which python3` from the terminal and got: `/usr/bin/python3`
I select the same python interpreter(command+shift+p) in vscode which point to the same path : `/usr/bin/python3`

I try to search from StackOverflow, most of the answers said terminal and vs code use the different python version, but it seems my python version is the same.

I don't have a clue and am stuck in here for a whole day. Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you share the appropriate directory structure you have along with the version of your vscode and python and the link to the package you installed ? Also in the meantime please continue to execute using terminal and do not waste time till we find a solution.

Comment: Thank you @TanishqVyas. Vscode 1.52.1 and put it under Applications(macos), I choose the python interpreter in the same path. Terminal shows Python 3.7.3; The GitHub link is github.com/oaxiom/glbase3, i cloned it to /Users/mymac/my_repo and add export PYTHONPATH=/Users/mymac/myrepo_repo/:$PYTHONPATH, then i source ~/.bash_profile. Also in .bash_profile, follows the anaconda path: ``` ... too long... /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda /opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" ```

Comment: Do you have your vscode open in root different than your project root ?

Comment: Hi @TanishqVyas, I'm a bit confused. You mean open vscode in root permission ?  I run vscode(/Application/visual studio code.app) and python scripts(/Users/mymac/Desktop/myfolder/my_python_scripts) with admin permission.

Comment: No, I meant do u have just the file open ? or do u have the root directory open ? or do u have the project folder open ?

Comment: @TanishqVyas I use vscode for default tools for opening `.py` format scripts. I just double clicked the script, so I think it should be just the file open.

Comment: Please try opening the folder of your project through vscode and then try to run it once. I have faced a similar issue which got solved when I opened the folder then the file rather than just double clicking the file.